# Selecting an element nested inside multiple parents in css

Tags: css, css-selectors

How would I get the p element from the following below? I'm trying to reset the color property(basically setting it to none or something to that degree) for this specific p tag. Any help is appreciated.

```
<div class="a">
  <ul class="b">
    <li class="c">
      <p> 
        <a class="d" href="#"> my text </a>
      </p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: There are multiple ways we can select an element, nesting with multiple parent is not an issue until there is any overriding of styles. Please be specific with your problem

Answer (score 0):

```
.a ul.b li.c p { 
   color: //some color
}
```

but `a` by default will have blue color, to change that

```
.a ul.b li.c p a { 
   color: //some color
}
```

if you want it to not change color on hover and focus then

```
    .a ul.b li.c p a, .a ul.b li.c p a:hover, .a ul.b li.c p a:focus { 
       color: //some color
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`.c > p` would do

unless there are multi `p` tags and you want to target the a specific one

then you can use `.c > p:nth-of-type(n)` where `n` is the number of the `p` element in the markup.

```css
body {
  color: green
}

.c>p {
  color: red
}

.c>p:nth-of-type(2) {
  color: blue
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  Class .a
  <ul class="b">
    Class .b
    <li class="c">
      <p>
        first Class .c
        <a class="d" href="#"> link in first class .c </a>
      </p>
      <p>
        second Class .c
        <a class="d" href="#"> link in second class .c </a>
      </p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```